# Email address not verified when I try to use aws ses in localstack

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-sdk, localstack

I'm trying to use localstack to test a lambda that use SES to send some emails.

But when I try it , I get the next error:

> Email address not verified

Is there any way to verified this email in localstack (docker)?

Thanks!

pd: Sorry for my English

Comment: This looks like its related to this: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/339

Comment: thanks @DavidWebster, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

Use the AWS CLI to verify the sender email:

```
aws ses verify-email-identity --email-address sender@example.com --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566
```