Email address not verified when I try to use AWS STS assume-tole session for AWS SES in LocalStack
I'm trying to use LocalStack to test SES to send some emails using temporary credentials received by aws sts assume-role
But when I try it, I get the next error:
Email address not verified

The problem can be solved by
aws ses verify-email-identity --email-address sender@example.com --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566

which is perfectly explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272839/email-address-not-verified-when-i-try-to-use-aws-ses-in-localstack/79310847#79310847
But, when I'm trying to use
aws sts assume-role

in order to receive temporary

AccessKeyId
SecretAccessKey
SessionToken

and then use these temprorarly credentials to send email I receive same error again, because list of verified emails becomes to empty for new session. Why?
